# How do I remove this old flue pipe?

Tags: concrete, chimney, demolition

There's an old chimney for a furnace in my basement which is no longer being used, and I'd like to take it out. It's going through cinder block, with concrete sealing around both sides.

[image: pipe coming through wall]

Outer diameter is 10", inner is 6", and it feels very solid -- almost like there's something between the inner and outer walls (is there?)

[image: exterior view]

Last year we had the roof replaced, and this no longer goes through it, so I'm just concerned with the wall penetration.

[image: exterior wide view]

Any tips on removal? I am guessing there's not much to disassemble here, and it'll mostly involve a sledgehammer, sawzall and prybars... is there any concern with whatever is in the lining?

---

EDIT: Done, rotary hammer made quick work of it.

[image: removed pipe - exterior view]
[image: removed pipe - inside view]

Comment: They insulated chimney pipes.  They just twist apart, like a beer cap.  The only hard(needing tools) would be the piece going though the wall.  It will depend on how well sealed it is to the wall.  Can probably leave it, by stuffing insulation inside and blocking the outside.  Might want an opening in the wall in the future for something.

Comment: Put that up for sale. You have a **lot of money**, even as used, there in stainless steel  class A chimney. Hope you didn't discard the parts already removed. No sawzall needed, it does just twist-lock and un-twist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe just disassembles, by twisting, then pulling. Usually counterclockwise, but you can examine the end at the top to verify.

At over $250/each piece new, handle those with care and save them for sale as used, rather than dropping and trashing them.

You appear to be contemplating an expensive destructive removal.

The wall connection will need to you use a long masonry bit (rent a drill capable of doing that if you don't own one) around it to free it up so you can remove it without destroying it. I believe if you check the cost of that part alone you'll find the used sales price pays for the tool rental, easily. And sawing stailess steel is miserable work, while a rented SDS-Max with an 18" bit will go through the mortar around it easily.

Then fill in the hole with bricks and mortar or concrete as you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. They didn't need to twist, just kind of pressure-fit together (some came apart easier than others). Unfortunately I definitely damaged some in the process before I read this, but thanks for the heads up on their value. Masonry bit in the rotary hammer made quick work of the piece through the wall.